# Embed registration page on another page in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, embed

Currently you can get to the registration page by going here: user/register
I need to be able to embed the registration form on ANOTHER page. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the method suggested here: http://drupal.org/node/248275

a.k.a. embed the form using the PHP Code input filter:

```
<?php
  print drupal_get_form('user_register'); 
?>
```

However, there will be a few gotchas with trying to embed the user registration page anywhere besides /user/register, because of the way Drupal's User module is set up.

It might be better for you to form_alter the user registration form, so you can customize it to fit your needs. Or, you might be able to get by with adding a block specifically to the user registration page.

What exactly are you trying to achieve by adding the registration page somewhere else?

Comment: I need two seperate paths for the registration form. So I can distinguish between the normal registration, and the other one I need. But I think I just realised what I can do. Basically just have a fake paramter. Something like: user/register?isOther=yes and then user/register ... will try your method and mine now and see what works best! :-)

Comment: Awesome - glad you could get it done! Using URL params is a great way to achieve a great many things... but you might want to use a Cookie param or something attached to the user token/session if it needs to me less hackable/more secure.